# k8s: how to reach services behind ingresses

Tags: kubernetes

This is my current ingress:

```
$ kubectl get ingress -o wide
NAME                   HOSTS          ADDRESS      PORTS   AGE
chart-1580851873-dev   feedly.local   172.18.0.2   80      3m21s
```

I've added this on my `/etc/hosts`:

```
172.18.0.2      *.local
```

This is my nodes ip:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION         INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE   KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k3d-k3s-worker-1   Ready    <none>   6d3h   v1.17.0+k3s.1   172.18.0.3    <none>        Unknown    5.3.0-28-generic   containerd://1.3.0-k3s.5
k3d-k3s-worker-0   Ready    <none>   6d3h   v1.17.0+k3s.1   172.18.0.4    <none>        Unknown    5.3.0-28-generic   containerd://1.3.0-k3s.5
k3d-k3s-server     Ready    master   6d3h   v1.17.0+k3s.1   172.18.0.2    <none>        Unknown    5.3.0-28-generic   containerd://1.3.0-k3s.5
```

I'm trying to get reach my service behind `feedly.local`...

These are my service and running pods:

```
$ kubectl get services -o wide
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE     SELECTOR
chart-1580851873-dev   ClusterIP   10.43.17.2   <none>        8080/TCP   7m26s   app.kubernetes.io/instance=chart-1580851873,app.kubernetes.io/name=dev

$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
chart-1580851873-dev-79f8df5858-bp9wx   1/1     Running   0          7m48s   10.42.2.35   k3d-k3s-worker-0   <none>           <none>
```

**Important: I don't want to run `kubectl proxy` neither `port-forwarding`.** I want to get access to internal kubernetes dns service in order to reach services behind ingresses.

Any ideas?

Comment: Service's aren't normally accessible outside of a cluster unless you use a `NodePort` or `type=LoadBalancer`. Can you describe your environment in a bit more detail? What are you running k3s on? Are there VM's involved? Do you have the default traefik ingress deployed?

Comment: First thing is that `/etc/hosts` don't support wild cards so this entry that you placed won`t work. 
Can you please post your ingress and ingress service yaml definitions?

Answer (score 0):

To fully link your local workstation into the internal cluster network you can look at tools like Telepresence or VPNs like WireGuard. That said, this is probably a bad idea, the point of the internal network is that its internal. If you want to expose a service, do that through the Service system. If you want access for debugging either use port-forward or `kubectl run -it` a temporary pod with a shell and tools you need.